# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innnerHTML' of null on a var data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the sample HTML I am trying to run but it fails.  Can someone tell me what is wrong?  Thanks

```html
<html>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
<body>
<svg width=100 height=350>
<circle fill='red'></circle>
<circle fill='orange'></circle>
<circle fill='yellow'></circle>
<circle fill='green'></circle>
<circle fill='blue'></circle>
<circle fill='purple'></circle>
</svg>
</body>
<script>
var data = [4,8,15,16,23,42];
// Enter code here
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
d3.selectAll("circle").data(data)
  .attr("cx",50)
  .attr("cy",function(d,i) {return 50 + i*50;})
  .attr('r',function(d) {return d;});
</script></html>
```

Comment: where's the element with `id="data"` ?

Comment: I am assuming that the var data is the "id".

Comment: you assume wrong - read the [documentation for getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Hmm, this is how my university instructor presented it. Wonder how in the heck he got it to work.

Comment: you probably missed something

Comment: Mistype on part still gets the error.

Comment: Not surprising fixing innerHTML doesn't fix the problem, since `document.getElementById("data")` is null regardless

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need this line: document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;